# When pressing the back button the application closes in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As the title says after pressing the back button, the application closes.

```
Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, top: 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colorYellow,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
      height: 40,
      width: 40,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white, size: 20),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: I don't think you need to put `true` inside pop(). Maybe that's the problem? Can you give more code so we can check if there is something you are missing?

Comment: i am also try with out true its also not working

Comment: The reason that the app is crashing might be because Flutter can't find anything to pop() out of. Is there any error given in the terminal? Maybe you can try `Navigator.pop(context)`.

Comment: i am applying this one also . same issue

Comment: Hi! Don't actually understand what you want to get and whats wrong. Please explain.

Answer (score 9):

You can try changing android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback in AndroidManifest from true to false.

*android>app>src>main>AndroidManifest.xml*

**Before**

```
android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"
```

**After**

```
android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="false"
```

Comment: I had the same issue, but this solution worked for me. @Parth-Prajapati Should mark this as the answer. After updating the code in the manifest file, I had to uninstall the app and install it again to start fresh.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your Scaffold with [WillPopScope](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html). Whenever the back button is pressed, you will get a callback at onWillPop, which returns a Future. If the Future returns true, the screen is popped.

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
        // await showDialog or Show add banners or whatever
        // return true if the route to be popped
         return false; // return false if you want to disable device back button click
       },
      child: Scaffold(),
     ),
  };
```

`return false;` which means your application not going to close on back button click

Answer (score 1):

Use `Navigator.pop(context);` instead of `Navigator.of(context).pop()`

Comment: i am applying this one also . same issue

Comment: Can you paste your issue on here ?

Comment: no error display app is crash when click on it

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same issue. When implemented flutter_stripe. Changing `**FlutterFragmentActivity**` to `**FlutterActivity**` solved the Issue. Don't know the cause

---

Comment: i did the same but now stripe initialization getting error, So how to handle tha?

Comment: setting android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback to false in menifest file worked for me. I was also having this issue while integrating stripe

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future<bool> onBackPress(context) {
        return showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Do you wish to exit?'),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      child: Text('Cancel'),
                      onPressed: () => {Navigator.pop(context, false)},
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () => {Navigator.pop(context, true)},
                        child: Text('Exit'))
                  ],
                ));
      }
    
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: () => onBackPress(context),
          child: SafeArea(),
     )};
```